# Own free() in c | melt free data blocks

Tags: c, memory-management, merge, malloc, free

i had to write my own free & malloc function. 
So far I have not had a problem with that, but now I am supposed to merge neighboring free memory blocks in the halde_free() function. I would be really grateful if you could help me there.

```
    #include "halde.h"
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>

/// Magic value for occupied memory chunks.
#define MAGIC ((void*)0xbaadf00d)

/// Size of the heap (in bytes).
#define SIZE (1024*1024*1)

/// Memory-chunk structure.
struct mblock {
    struct mblock *next;
    size_t size;
    char memory[];
};

/// Heap-memory area.
char memory[SIZE];

/// Pointer to the first element of the free-memory list.
static struct mblock *head;

/// Helper function to visualise the current state of the free-memory list.
void halde_print(void) {
    struct mblock* lauf = head;

    // Empty list
    if ( head == NULL ) {
        fprintf(stderr, "(empty)\n");
        return;
    }

    // Print each element in the list
    while ( lauf ) {
        fprintf(stderr, "(addr: 0x%08zx, off: %7zu, ", (uintptr_t) lauf, (uintptr_t)lauf - (uintptr_t)memory);
        fflush(stderr);
        fprintf(stderr, "size: %7zu)", lauf->size);
        fflush(stderr);

        if ( lauf->next != NULL ) {
            fprintf(stderr, "  -->  ");
            fflush(stderr);
        }
        lauf = lauf->next;
    }
    fprintf(stderr, "\n");
    fflush(stderr);
}

void *halde_malloc (size_t size) {
    static int initialized = 0;

    if(initialized == 0){
        head = (struct mblock *) memory;
        head->size = sizeof(memory) - sizeof (struct mblock);
        head->next = NULL;
        initialized = 1;
    }

    if(size == 0){
        return NULL;
    }

    struct mblock *lauf = head;
    struct mblock **prev_next = &head;

    while (lauf != NULL && lauf->size < size){
        prev_next = &(lauf->next);
        lauf = *prev_next;
    }

    if(lauf == NULL){
        errno = ENOMEM;
        return NULL;
    }

    if((lauf->size -size) <= sizeof(struct mblock)){
        *prev_next = lauf->next;
    } else {
        //mblock anlegen und init.
        struct mblock* neu = (struct mblock*) (lauf->memory + size);
        neu->size = lauf->size - sizeof(struct mblock) - size;
        neu->next = lauf->next;

        //mblock anpassen
        lauf->size = size;

        //verketten wiederherstellen
        *prev_next = neu;
    }

    lauf->next = MAGIC;

    return lauf->memory;
}

void halde_free (void *ptr) {
    if(ptr == NULL){
        return;
    }

    struct mblock *mbp = (struct mblock *) ptr - 1;
    if(mbp->next != MAGIC){
        abort();
    } else {
        mbp->next = head;
        head = mbp;
    }
}
```

The code works so far but i have really no idea how to merge blocks.. 
The memory management runs over a simply linked lists. The variable head points to the first free memory block.

My idea is to merge the blocks directly in the else part but i don't have a good idea to do that..

Comment: I don't get why you're comparing the next pointer to MAGIC and aborting if that's not what's there.

Comment: If you malloc a block the next element of this block is MAGIC. (lauf->next = MAGIC;) 

And in the free() you have to check if the element you want to free can be freed at all or if it is already free.

Comment: This is rather broad question. So you have a linked list, with list items representing memory blocks. And then you need to find the list items which point to adjacent memory blocks, and remove one, and fix start and length of the other to cover the memory area of both. Simple brute force way would be to traverse the free list, and test if the freed block can be merged with existing free block (either before or after), and then add it as last in the list if no suitable merge candidate was found.

Comment: After that works, you might want to check if the newly enlarged free block could now be merged too (in case the freed block filled a gap between two free blocks).

Comment: A more efficient solution would involve using some more advanced data structure (such as a tree of some kind) to hold the free blocks, so you wouldn't have to traverse the entire list to find possible merge candidates. Slight improvement could be achieved by keeping the free list sorted (which is basically free, since you need to traverse it anyway), so you can stop searching earlier.